# java- program just hangs after initial user input (file i/o)

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, file-io

I am trying to write a guessing game program. In this game the user provides a list of words to the program.  The program randomly selects one of the words to be guessed from this list.  The player then guesses letters in an attempt to figure out what the hidden word might be.  The number of guesses that the user takes are tracked and reported at the end of the game.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a filename containing your wordlist: ");
    String name = sc.next();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(name));
    ArrayList<String> list1 = getList(sc);
    System.out.println("Read " + list1.size() + " words from the file");

    ...
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

After the program asks the user to enter the filename, nothing happens, and I am not too sure why.

Comment: `getList(sc)` ... spent some time in rethinking ***which*** `Scanner` instance you what to pass here.

Comment: Yes, that seemed to be the problem. I also had an error where it would ask the user for a character and then it would just pretend like i didnt enter anything. Turned out using next() was a better option than nextLine()